# Best way in Django/PostgreSQL to manage reservations and cancellations of things in a limited pool

Tags: django, postgresql, deadlock

Using Django/PostgreSQL, what is a scalable way (a million users) to safely track reservations and cancellations for virtual things in a limited pool?

Consider an example where users are offered items, but each item has a maximum number of "takes". One item might be balloons where we can give away 100,000 and another is an extra game life where we can only give away 1000. Each can accept or decline the item within 5 minutes.

One implementation is to add deltas +1 and -1 for every reservation/cancellation and use the sum to figure out how many are left (this avoids updates and deletes on the DB). What's a better way to do this (including using something other than a RDB)?

```
class User(models.Model):
    # ....

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=256)
    max_gives = IntegerField()

class ItemAccepted(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=256)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Reservation(models.Model):
    delta = models.IntegerField('Delta')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)

@transaction.commit_on_success
def reserve_item(item_id, user)

    # This should lock the item row until the transaction commits
    item = Item.objects.select_for_update().get(id=item_id)

    # Now it should be safe to count the reservations
    num_reservations = Reservation.objects.filter(item=item)\
        .aggregate(Sum('delta'))['delta__sum'])

    # If we have reserved the maximum # of items, return
    if num_reservations >= item.max_gives:
        return False

    # Otherwise, reserve the item
    res = Reservation(delta=1, item=item, receiver=user)
    res.save()
    return True

def decline_item(item_id, user):
    item = Item.objects.get(id=item_id)
    Reservation(delta=-1, item=item, receiver=user).save()

def accept_item(item_id, user)
    item = Item.objects.get(id=item_id)
    AcceptedItem(item=item, receiver=user).save()
```

Comment: Good on you for actually thinking about concurrency issues. I was halfway through writing the usual "this is racey as can be" when I realised that you'd done a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` of the item row.

Comment: Thanks! It's been working well, but the load isn't tremendous right now and I'm expecting it to increase. I'm not sure it will scale and was wondering if there was a better way or more appropriate tool.